# How can you replace exisiting data list with the new data on the second search click?

Tags: javascript

This is a `onclick` button function that creates an unordered list of the users search query that stops at 10 examples. But when the users make another search, it creates another batch of 10 examples that extend the page. How can I replace the previous batch with the new batch?

```
$("#search").click(function(){

   var clickInputValue = $("#value").val();                
   var wikiApi = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+ clickInputValue +'&format=json&callback=?'                

   $.getJSON(wikiApi, function (data){

       for(var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++){

          $("#resultOutput").append("<div><li><a target='_blank' href="+data[3][i]+"><h2>" + data[1][i]+ "</h2>" + "<p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></a></li></div>");
       };

   });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just empty the container before you start looping and adding new ones

```
$.getJSON(wikiApi, function (data){
    $("#resultOutput").empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++){
    ......
```

Comment: It works, but it stops at one example instead of 10. Any idea?

Comment: No idea what that means. Your output should be 10 if you had 20 before and only empty the container before the loop starts

Comment: Then you didn't do it right. Your loop should be exactly the same as before

Comment: Youre right, I didn't put the code before the loop, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the DIV before appending items

```
$("#resultOutput").html('')

for(var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++){...
```

Comment: Right...I wrote that before your edit when the html() method was inside the loop